# Making a hyperlink inside a button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, hyperlink

I have a button on my asp.net page that (upon mouseover) needs to act like a hyperlink (the hand cursor).  I cannot use a linkbutton because I need the GUI of a regular asp:button.

Is there a way to create the hyperlink cursor on mouseover?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this into your button's markup...

style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"

so...

```
<asp:Button id="test" text="test" runat="server" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" />
```

Comment: You're welcome.  This was the quick and dirty way.  If you find that there are many of these buttons you need to do this to, I would recommend the CSS Class solution that the others have been offering as their answers.

Answer (score 5):

Using css you can say:

```
.anchor {cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;}
```

and then in your aspx:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="anchor" ... >
```

Comment: doesn't change to the hand icon :(

Comment: What browser? You might want to change it to `{cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;}`

Comment: I am on IE, but customers will have Chrome, FF etc

Comment: I tested this (the orignal answer) in Ie9, FF6, and Chrome 13.  It worked just fine.  Cursor:hand is a throw back to ancient IE and is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I forgot about old IE.

Comment: And by ancient, I mean 5.5... which doesn't really exist anymore.  cursor:pointer has worked in everything from IE6 up and ALL others (Firefox, chrome, opera, even safari)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following for the hand cursor on button mouse over:

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" CssClass="ButtonClass" />`

The in a style sheet or inline in the page itself define the class:

`.ButtonClass
{
cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}`

Use both (pointer and hand) for cross browser compatibility.